# Google Wildcard Use

Tags: search, wildcard

I am looking to use google (or another search engine) in order to provide websites relating the name of an individual with various different variations of a job title

For example

Bob Williams or 
Bobby Williams or
Bert Williams or
Barbara Williams or 
Bettie Williams
and so on

plus one of the following job types - estate agent/banker/author/publisher etc

I have tried "B * " + Williams + Banker and ("B * " + "Williams") + Lawyer and unfortunately have not been able to get the results I require.  Can anyone assist with providing me with the correct syntax and which search engine is best to use.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Google does not support this, but does something similar when you are searching

If you search for "Bob" then the engine search for `*bob*`

So, i guess you cannot do what you are searching for